# I have an in-app purchase set up, and it works, except when the user presses "cancel" it still ends up buying the product

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When the iPad prompts you to "Confirm your In-App purchase", if you hit "Cancel" then it seems to still buy the product for the user. Because if I then try to buy it again, and then DO confirm the purchase, then it gives me an alert saying "You've already purchased this. Would you like to get it again for free?"

Note: this is all in the environmental sandbox, so maybe that is the reason? Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)makePurchase:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

-(void)getProductInfo: (drawKitViewController *) viewController
{

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                      initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                      [NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        request.delegate = self;

        [request start];
    }
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        _product = products[0];
            }
    else {

    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                 [self unlockCreateAccount];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your in app purchase product is `Non-consumable`. This means once you have successfully bought this product. You don't need to buy it again.
If you still try to buy it instead of restore previous bought product, you will get the alert "You've already purchased this. Would you like to get it again for free?".

BTW: You **MUST** supply user the entrance to restore previous bought product feature in your app. Otherwise your app will be rejected (my experience).

Comment: I'm saying if you try to buy the product, but then at the final screen where it asks you to confirm the purchase, and then you click "NO", canceling the sale, then it still seems to give the user the product.

Comment: What leads up to your `makePurchase` method being called?  Have you put a breakpoint in that method to make sure that it isn't being called when you click NO?

Answer (score 1):

This is the line that executes the purchase operation

`[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];`

As long as you don't execute this code when the user cancels the operation, the purchase won't go through.

However, for a non-consumable purchase, if your test user has purchased the item at any time in the past you will get the message you described.  The only things you can do is set up a new test Apple id for purchasing or create a different in-app product.

Comment: Thanks, but does it only happen in the Test mode? Or can a user (in production mode) get the item for free the second time?

Comment: A non-consumable is only purchased once, so they don't get "for free a second time". They already own it and the App Store knows it, so the purchase is completed at zero cost and your app sees it as a purchase so that it can unlock whatever the purchase is, but they only ever had to pay for it once

Comment: I actually knew that. But the problem is in my app (in testing mode), if you click the buy button first (the purchase is made and user gets the points) and then again, a popup comes "for free a second time" and if they choose "yes" on it, they again gets those points (I'm actually adding these points). But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: It sounds like you have the wrong in app purchase type. You want a consumable in app purchase, not a non-consumable.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention to it. I was able to solve it, let me know if I should delete my comments on your post to keep it clean and clear :)